# fire a second ajax request whilst in a setInterval loop

Tags: javascript, polling

I have a javascript function which polls the existence of an HTML file, and when it's discovered displays the content. 
That works fine... but what I want to do is call a 2nd function whilst it's running those checks... i.e. whilst the file doesn't exist... 
However that 2nd function only works once the file exists... otherwise in my chrome deveopment tools it just shows as (pending)

Any ideas what might be causing it?

```
function checkfile(fileNamePassed, userCode, typeOfReport, proof, passedDate){

    var timerForLoadingResult=setInterval( function() { checkServerForFile(fileNamePassed, userCode, typeOfReport, proof, passedDate); }, 3000 );

function checkServerForFile(fileNamePassed, userCode, typeOfReport, proof) { 
        var d = new Date();   
        var newDate=d.getFullYear()+'-'+(d.getMonth()+1)+'-'+d.getDate()+'.'+d.getHours()+'.'+d.getMinutes()+'.'+d.getSeconds();

        checkReportRequests(passedDate);

          $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://example.com/wwl/htmlPolling/'+fileNamePassed+'.html',
                    type:'HEAD',
                    error: function()
                    {

                    },
                    success: function()
                    {
                        clearInterval(timerForLoadingResult);
                        $("#generateReports").attr('onclick',"generateReports('"+typeOfReport+"','"+proof+"','"+userCode+"','"+newDate+"')");
                        $("#main").load('https://example.com/wwl/htmlPolling/'+fileNamePassed+'.html');
                        $('[id=wait]').hide();  
                        $('[id=wrapper]').hide();   
                        $('[id=main]').show();  
                    }
                });
            }
}
```

The 2nd function that is called is:

```
function checkReportRequests(passedDate){


            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    data: (
                    {
                        "type": "checkReportRequests",
                        "passedDate": passedDate         
                    }), 

                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        $("#statusCheck").html(response);
                    }
                });


}
```

the function works because it displays the result once the polling has finished... but the whole point is that it updates throughout!

[image]

Comment: "_otherwise in my chrome deveopment tools it just shows as (pending)_" can you post screen shots of devtools network tab showing a sample run ?

Comment: added picture with thanks

Comment: In "ajax.php" do you have any blocking code like set `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` and `sleep(10)`?

Comment: I think it is better to make another setInterval for the `checkReportRequests` function; but before that make sure that the server side is working well for that request.

Comment: I think the problem is being caused by the fact that I've another process going on connecting to the database and generating files in the background... the process pends and times out time and time again, until the main process has finished and then it will run successfully... is there a way around it? I want to be able to connect to the database and check a status whilst another ajax call is also reading / writing from the database...

Comment: @shadysherif the function works fine if it runs at the very beginning or end of my polling... it fails anywhere in the middle and I think this is because another process is going on generating reports based on the mysql database and generating PDF files etc. Seems I can't do another request connurrently.... not sure how to troubleshoot that.

Comment: could it be an IIS server issue? Perhaps it's not letting me run more php scripts until the one generating the reports has finished? It takes a couple of minutes to run.

Comment: I'm not happy to call this a solution - but I have made a work around.... calling another PHP script won't work... subsequent ones will only PEND... instead in the PHP script taht's already running I create a small HTML file with the number of reports created... i.e. 4/10 and then in the original polling ajax I load the content of the created file into a DIV... accomplishes the same thing, but it feels limiting not to be able to start new PHP processes until the previous one finishes....?

Comment: Not that much experience working on windows hosting, but can you tell the configuration?

Comment: can you try to make this concurrent call using any rest client ex: postman. If it is a server problem write a new question with iis tags because of your question wouldn't be about js itself.